# add Page Base Navigation In watch kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, watchkit

Got stuck with page base navigation. I have added the relationship with three Interface controller as shown image below, which is not  Main Entry Point. I am calling the calendar Interface controller from other Interface Controller programmatically.

```
     [self pushControllerWithName:@"calendarIC" context:nil];
```

If I add the entry point to this Interface Controller, Pages gets added as required.But I don't want to add entry point to this Controller [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a page-based and hierarchical interface controllers together in WatchKit.  According to the Apple docs they are mutually exclusive.

> For WatchKit apps with more than one screen of content, you must
>   choose a navigation style at design time. The navigation style you
>   choose defines how you present and manage interface controllers in
>   your apps. WatchKit supports two interface styles, which are **mutually**
>   **exclusive**:
>
> - Hierarchical
> - Page-based

Answer (score 0):

You can combine page-based and hierarchical interface controllers together, if you use a modal segue as entry point for your page based navigation.